# push notifications stopped working in app after cert update

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

My cert for push notifications expired a few days ago. I updated it on the developer portal and put the new one for my server to use. Everything works not for the app that is downloaded from the app store.

When i try to load a in-dev build from x-code all push notifications fail. Apple responds back with message "Invalid Token".

I have literally done nothing. I just started it up and started testing to make sure everything is working. Is there some way to update the cert in the app or something of that sort??

NOTE: uploaded my app to testflight and everything works. Only does not work while developing right from xcode.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me but if your sending notification through your own server you need to generate new .pem file with new certificate. If you already does it or you are using other third party to send push please mention.

Answer (score 1):

- For developing you use different APN and Certificate that for
  Production.
- Apple generate different tokens for app in Debug and app
  in Production.
- Your server is using a Production certificate and a
  Production APN.
- TestFlight app is a Production ready app.

Now:

- In Debug you send a Debug token to a server in Production, that Debug token is NOT registered on Apple Production APN.
- In TestFlight you send a Production token to a server in Production, that Production token IS registered on Apple Production APN.

So all is working as intended.

Comment: p.s. This phrase "Everything works not for the app that is downloaded from the app store" doesn't make any sense, so I've ignored it when elaborating the answer.